# Overwriting layers in ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, arcgis-online

I am using ArcGIS Pro 3.0.3 and ArcGIS Online.

I am managing a set of planned power lines that are changing all the time. My colleagues need to see these changes, so we have set up a group on ArcGIS Online, where I overwrite the layer whenever changes occur.

My problem is that this often breaks the layer connection inside the map, and I get the `An error occured loading this layer` message.

Does it have something with other layers in my ArcGIS Pro map, that "overrides" the `layer ID` to ArcGIS Online?

For instance, I use that map for several other things, like analysis with other datasets, and they get autoassigned a `layer ID`, like this:

[image]

But can I find this `id` on ArcGIS Online somewhere, and do a check if they match before I overwrite the layer?

What checks do I have to do for the layer not to break when overwriting the shared feature layer on ArcGIS Online?

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was in the same situation. I have over 200 layers in my organisation, and whenever an update was required, I faced difficulties replacing the layer. Because it also brakes the connection that it has with web-maps and web-applications.

My suggestions are:

1 - Do not replace the layer, but use a status field (approved, inactive, old design) and create the symbology according to this field. Then upload the new design as approved (or new, active, current) and mark the old design as old (or inactive, deprecated, historical)

2 - Load your layer directly in ArcGIS pro, delete all rows and append the new updated design. More practical but you lose the history of the project (you can keep it locally).

Im using the second one by the way.

Answer (score 3):

I think the best practice is just edit the published feature service.
Just load the service into ArcGIS Pro and edit it there. The changes are instantly applied once you save the edits.
You need to make the service editable when you publish it though. Check the settings of the hosted layer permissions. You can check how to set and manage permissions [**here**](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/manage-data/manage-editing-hfl.htm).

Publishing and overwriting the service should be done when you change the data structure or maybe set a different symbology.

Answer (score 0):

You should go to the properties of the Map and set the "Allow assignment of unique numeric IDs in the Properties dialog".

[image: Set unique ids on layers]

For more info check out the following link:**https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/sharing/overview/assign-layer-ids.htm**